# Which hypothesis test to perform to check if the sample has more constant members?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

**Problem statement:**

> Articles in a factory are produced with weights following a normal distribution with $ X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. A few changes are made in the factory and a random sample of weights of newly produced articles is collected $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{10})$. Which hypothesis test should I perform to test if the new system is making more *constant* weights?

I understand that we somehow have to take variance into account to build a test statistic which could help us test our hypothesis but I am not able to understand which one to use. Any help (with references) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a variance test. Do you see another option?

Comment: I have read about the tests involving mean comparision yet. Did you mean ANOVA?

Comment: Since “ANOVA” has “variance” in the name, it is reasonable to think it refers to a test of variances. For better or for worse, ANOVA most definitely is not a test of variances. ANOVA is a test of means that cleverly uses a test of variances to infer something about means. I am referring to testing something like $H_0: \sigma^2_1=\sigma^2_2$ vs $H_a: \sigma ^2_1\ne\sigma^2_2$. Does this look like what you would want? (There’s a relationship between this kind of test and how ANOVA cleverly uses a test of variances to make inferences about means, but there are a few steps to connect the two.)

Comment: Got it. How would the alternate hypothesis look like if we are saying that the new system makes more constant weights? $H_0 : \sigma_1^2 \ge \sigma_2^2$ vs $H_a : \sigma_1^2 < \sigma_2^2$? Would testing for a smaller sample variance be appropriate for this use case?

Comment: The exact phrasing is bizarre. If this were something a customer asked me to test, I would ask what they mean like a good consultant does. However, for a course exercise, it sure seems like it is asking for a variance test. With that in mind, would it be reasonable to assume a normal distribution after the changes are made in the factory?